# Laravel Authentication With Two Tables

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to use Laravel's built-in [Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) class. Upon reading it, it seems that it only looks into one table as per the `config/auth.php` file. As per the doc, I can use syntax like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

My concern is, the `email` column is in my **user** table while `password` is in **auth** table. As I stated above, my understanding of Laravel's authentication is it only looks for one table only. Did I miss something?

Comment: I assume you have some relation between the two, like a `user_id` column in the `auth` table. Is that correct?

Comment: The nice way here is to create a custom auth driver that checks the password from the different table and doesn't require any changes to the code you already have. But I need to know the relation between your tables to post a correct answer.

Comment: Hi @Bogdan, yes the two tables has a relation. The `id` of **user** table is foreigned key to the `user_id` column of **auth** table..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the solution is fantastically simple. You just need to override the `getAuthPassword` method which is defined in the [`Authenticatable`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/Authenticatable.php#L22-L25) trait, by adding this to your `User` model:

```php
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return \DB::table('auth')->where('user_id', $this->id)->pluck('password');
}
```

And that's it, now the authentication system will get the password from the `auth` table before checking if it matches with user input.

Comment: Thanks for this @Bogdan, one more question please, can you please pinpoint me where on the code can I see the declaration of `getKey()` and `getKeyName()`? I am seeing this method being used but nowhere explained in documentation the complete list of such methods.

Comment: When you have `$this->methodName()` it means that the method is defined either by that class, a trait that the class uses, or a class that it extends. Since those methods are not defined by the `Authenticatable` trait or the `User` class which uses that trait, it stands to reason that they are defined by a class that the `User` model [`extends`](http://bit.ly/1T5YxCv). In this case that class is [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php), which is the base class used for all Eloquent models.

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate user manually.

1. Retrieve user from your `user` table by email with his password from
   `auth` table (via simple join or eloquent relations).
2. Validate that password is correct using `\Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword);` .
3. Login user manually using`Auth::login($user);` if you are using Eloquent or `Auth::loginUsingId($id);` if simple DB query.

Docs:

- Auth http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#other-authentication-methods
- Hash http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing

Comment: Thanks for the answer, well there goes my problem. How can I validate the password if it is correct since I am not familiar in using the Authentication feature of Laravel.

Comment: @Saitimang I've updated my answer, so take a look. Hope it helps

Comment: Actually @Bogdans answer is better. His solution is more elegant, if you are using eloquent :)